# How to store 4-byte character in MySQL 5.5 using ruby (mysql2 gem)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3, mysql2

My problem is my API server can not store a character which is possible to display on iOS client. The character is `1F49D` (http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/128157).

Server side:

- ruby 1.9.3-p327
- activerecord 3.2 with mysql2
- MySQL server: 5.5.28

FYI:

1. previously our iOS client used parse.com as persistence service. Now, we move to our owned API server (implemented in ruby).
2. When I try with `irb`. Ruby 1.9 is possible to read and understand this character.
3. Here is the text containing character. https://gist.github.com/jacobdam/6220339/raw/1562815fe37df04293d3cee7d216e920415de715/gistfile1.txt
4. I changed the schema, table, column collation to `utf8` and `utf16`. But it does not work.

Anyone can give me an advice how to persist/retreive this text to/from mysql?

Comment: You need to use [utf8mb4 charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) instead of utf8(mb3) (implies MySQL >= 5.5.3)

Comment: Thanks @julp, `utf8mb3` works now. Can you post it an answer, so I can accept your answer? :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed typo. I meant `utf8mb4`. It took me a long research. Because I am not sure if it's a problem of ruby language, or mysql2 gem, or MySQL, or AR, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prerequisite: MySQL >= 5.5.3

Character set named utf8 (or utf8mb3) uses a maximum of three bytes per character and contains only BMP characters. In order to have a maximum of four bytes per character, you need to:

1. switch charset/collation of all your tables/columns to [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)
2. edit your config/database.yml to change the `encoding: utf8` lines to `encoding: utf8mb4`

(and a recent mysql2 gem?)

Comment: Yeah. `mysql2` gem v0.3.13. `mysql2` must be installed after `mysql 5.5.3+` installed.